# Quick Reg expression for .htm

Tags: php, regex

Can someone illustrate how I do a simple reg expression to match a string that ends with .htm

eg. floor.htm would match etc..

Comment: This is fairly easy just searching up regex for finding a file i found it. you just change the ending to whatever you want. In this case a .html file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just match ".htm", and anchor it at the end of the string with `$`. Note you have to escape the `.`, which means "match any character":

```
/\.htm$/
```

Answer (score 2):

this will do the job for you ;-)

```
/\.htm$/
```

Try to learn regex they are very helpful and pretty cool to know.

Comment: Should have probably stated that I am using codeigniter with the routes feature to do the following:

$route['hotel/pages/([a-z0-9_-]+)//\.htm$/']
So a page with the following would match
site.com/hotel/pages/somesection/somepage.htm

Answer (score 1):

Other way is like:

```
$string = 'some_string_here.htm';
$pattern = '/\.htm\z/';
preg_match($pattern, $string);
```